# Binding specific interface IP address to Azure Storage container connections

Tags: azure-storage

Our product has software-managed virtual networks and has multiple local IP addresses from which network communications could be routed. One of the requirements we have is to ensure that outgoing traffic is routed from a specific, desired local IP when communicating with the Azure blob storage endpoint.

The Azure SDK does not seem to expose any means of specifying which local IP address to use for communications to the Azure blob endpoint.  Please let us know if you think the SDK does expose and if so how we can utilize the facility.

If not, we are evaluating making changes to the azure-storage-java SDK source in order to support the local IP binding requirement.

Has this kind of situation been brought to your attention before? Do you have any suggestions as to how this might be accomplished?

Thanks,
Sowmya.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? We have a windows azure cloud service which records data on a queue. This queue is accessible via the public endpoint, but that IP address appears to be dynamic. Thus, we have an issue with allowing that endpoint thru our internal firewall in order to listen to the queue.